# How to persist a routing to local routing table in CentOs 7?

Tags: networking, routing

Let's say we have a CentOS machine with an IP like 10.123.10.10, and we also want it to handle requests coming to subnet 10.0.0.0/11. Whether these requests come locally or via some other routing is not relevant here. For this, we have successfully used a local routing with command

```
sudo ip route add local 10.0.0.0/11 dev eth0
```

But the issue is that this routing disappears from the local table on machine restart. **What is the correct way to persist this in CentOS 7.9?**

I have tried adding a route

```
10.0.0.0/11 via 127.0.0.1
```

to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`, but this has had no effect.

Is there a way to do this, or should I just add that command to some startup script?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface name>` are parsed in two ways:

- the legacy way: if it contains triplets of environment-variable-like assignments of `NETWORK<N>=`, `NETMASK<N>=` and `GATEWAY<N>=` (where `<N>` is a number), those are used to construct network routes.
- the modern way: after filtering out any legacy triplets, each remaining non-empty line is prefixed with `ip route add` (and maybe suffixed with `dev <interface name>` matching the filename), and the resulting command line is executed. This is repeated if the file contains multiple lines.

I haven't tried this, but if your `sudo ip route add local 10.0.0.0/11 dev eth0` does what you need, I'd try writing

```
local 10.0.0.0/11
```

into the `route-eth0` file.

Comment: Did not sadly have any effect, even after restarting interface or the machine. The rule does not show up on the local routing table.